# Ejecutar una multiplicación sólo si un Option especifico está seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, entrada

Verán, quiero aplicar a un valor que introduje en un input el valor que ya trae más el 13% que aquí en Costa Rica se aplica al IVA.

Mi formulario es el siguiente:

```
<table align="center">
<tr>
    <td colspan="2"><b>Datos del Artículo:</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Código UPC:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="upc" placeholder="7441053000000" title="Código de Barras" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" size="25" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Nombre del Producto:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="nomprod" size="25" title="Nombre del Producto" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Descripción:</td>
    <td><textarea rows="3" cols="20" name="descripcion" style="text-transform:uppercase;" onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();"></textarea></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Código Especial:</td>
    <td><select name="codesp">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione una opción...</option>
    <option title="V-Ingresos por Ventas de bienes y servicios" value="V-Ingresos por Ventas de bienes y servicios">V-Ingresos por Ventas de bienes y servicios</option>
    <option title="SP-Ingresos por Servicios Profesionales" value="SP-Ingresos por Servicios Profesionales">SP-Ingresos por Servicios Profesionales</option>
    <option title="A-Ingresos por Alquileres" value="A-Ingresos por Alquileres">A-Ingresos por Alquileres</option>
    <option title="I-Ingesos por Intereses" value="I-Ingesos por Intereses">I-Ingesos por Intereses</option>
    <option title="M-Ingresos por Comisiones de todo tipo" value="M-Ingresos por Comisiones de todo tipo">M-Ingresos por Comisiones de todo tipo</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Unidad de Medida:</td>
    <td><select name="unidadmedida">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione una opción...</option>
    <option title="Unidad - Unid" value="Unidad - Unid">Unidad - Unid</option>
    <option title="Gramo - g" value="Gramo - g">Gramo - g</option>
    <option title="Kilogramo - kg" value="Kilogramo - kg">Kilogramo - kg</option>
    <option title="Litro - L" value="Litro - L">Litro - L</option>
    <option title="Mililitro - mL" value="Mililitro - mL">Mililitro - mL</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Tipo de Producto:</td>
    <td><select name="tipoprod">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione una opción...</option>
    <option title="Abarrotes" value="Abarrotes">Abarrotes</option>
    <option title="Pan Konig" value="Pan Konig">Pan Konig</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Precio sin impuestos:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="precio" class="amt" name="precio" size="25" title="Precio sin Impuestos" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Gravamen:</td>
    <td><select name="gravamen" id="gravamen" onchange="impuestos(); suma();">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione una opción...</option>
    <option title="No paga impuestos" value="Exento">Exento</option>
    <option title="Sí paga impuestos" value="Gravado">Gravado</option>
    </select></td>
</tr>
<tr><input type="hidden" id="resultado" name="resultado" class="amt" />
    <td>Precio Final:</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="preciofinal" name="preciofinal" size="25" title="Precio con Impuestos" readonly="readonly" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="reset" title="Limpiar" value="Limpiar" /></td>
    <td align="center"><input type="submit" title="Guardar Producto" value="Guardar" /></td>
</tr>
```

Como verán tengo varios SELECT, pues en el SELECT llamado "gravamen" es donde quiero que se ejecute la magia. Tengo 2 Option, una llamada 'exento' y otra llamada 'gravamen'.

Lo que quiero es que al momento de seleccionar por ejemplo 'exento' no me modifique el valor, pues está exento de IVA. El valor ya llega por medio de un input tipo hidden y una función de suma de class por JS al input llamado Precio Final.

El problema es que no se me da como formular un IF en JS para que sólo si se escoge 'gravado' ejecute la multiplicación del value por 0.13. Al intentarlo me lo marca como NaN en el value del hidden.

El ejemplo en concreto sería este:

```js
function justNumbers(e)
        {
        var keynum = window.event ? window.event.keyCode : e.which;
        if ((keynum == 8) || (keynum == 46))
        return true;
         
        return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(keynum));
        }
//Esta es la funcion para el SELECT, donde quiero que solo se ejecute en el Option Gravado  
function impuestos(){
i = document.getElementById("precio").value;
r = i*0.13;
  document.getElementById("resultado").value = r;
}
//Esta es la funcion que suma el input del precio sin iva mas el resultado de la multiplicacion del select
function suma() {
      var add = 0;
      $('.amt').each(function() {
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
              add += Number($(this).val());
          }
      });
      $('#preciofinal').val(add);
  };
```

```css
.boo{font-family:Century Gothic;}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
     <td>Precio sin impuestos:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="precio" class="amt" name="precio" size="25" title="Precio sin Impuestos" onkeypress="return justNumbers(event);" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gravamen:</td>
        <td><select name="gravamen" id="gravamen" onchange="impuestos(); suma();">
        <option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione una opción...</option>
        <option title="No paga impuestos" value="Exento">Exento</option>
        <option title="Sí paga impuestos" value="Gravado">Gravado</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" id="resultado" name="resultado" class="amt" />
     <td>Precio Final:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="preciofinal" name="preciofinal" size="25" title="Precio con Impuestos" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer algo asi:

```js
$("#gravamen").on("change", function() {
  if($(this).val() == 'Exento') {
    $("#preciofinal").val($("#precio").val());
  } else {
    $("#preciofinal").val(parseInt($("#precio").val()) + $("#precio").val() * 0.13);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
     <td>Precio sin impuestos:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="precio" class="amt" name="precio" size="25" title="Precio sin Impuestos" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gravamen:</td>
        <td><select name="gravamen" id="gravamen" >
        <option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione una opción...</option>
        <option title="No paga impuestos" value="Exento">Exento</option>
        <option title="Sí paga impuestos" value="Gravado">Gravado</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" id="resultado" name="resultado" class="amt" />
     <td>Precio Final:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="preciofinal" name="preciofinal" size="25" title="Precio con Impuestos" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hola, pues fijate que no me funcionó, debido a que no se declara una función. Entiendo que se nombra al elemento $("#gravamen") pero al ejecutar el codigo no sucede nada...

Comment: Pues aqui si funciona correctamente, solo presiona el boton ejecutar, ingresa un numero en el input Precio sin impuestos y cambia el valor del Select Gravamen.

Comment: Sí, es lo raro.... Aquí se ejecuta súper bien. Literalmente copio todo el código y lo pego en el mío y no se ejecuta... lo extraño es que en la consola de depurar no aparece ningún error.

Comment: No necesitas la funcion impuestos(), en lugar de esa funcion copia mi codigo javascript.  Este codigo no necesita estar dentro de ninguna funcion.

Comment: Sí, la eliminé, y copie literal tu codigo. Seguro es el caché del browser. Probaré de nuevo

Comment: Lo acabo de copiar limpio, tal cual, como tu respuesta y no me funciona, de verdad que no entiendo... jajaja

Comment: Puedes editar tu respuesta con tu nuevo codigo para ver cual es el problema

Answer (score 0):

El código íntegro sería este, con tu código copiado.

```js
$("#gravamen").on("change", function() {
  if($(this).val() == 'Exento') {
    $("#preciofinal").val($("#precio").val());
  } else {
    $("#preciofinal").val(parseInt($("#precio").val()) + $("#precio").val() * 0.13);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<table>
<tr>
     <td>Precio sin impuestos:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="precio" class="amt" name="precio" size="25" title="Precio sin Impuestos" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Gravamen:</td>
        <td><select name="gravamen" id="gravamen" >
        <option selected="selected" value="">Seleccione una opción...</option>
        <option title="No paga impuestos" value="Exento">Exento</option>
        <option title="Sí paga impuestos" value="Gravado">Gravado</option>
        </select></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><input type="hidden" id="resultado" name="resultado" class="amt" />
     <td>Precio Final:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="preciofinal" name="preciofinal" size="25" title="Precio con Impuestos" readonly="readonly" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Aquí si que funciona, en mi secuencia con wampp server y browsers como firefox y chrome no va.